# State management with setState and bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, state, bloc

Is it good to use bloc and also setState for state management?
Basically, I’m using bloc to control the state when I need to share the state when others classes (screens), but I’m using setState inside reusable components like a text field, where I control the error messages, the obscure text, etc. Which I consider does not have to be inside the business logic as well.
So I was wondering if this is a good practice or not.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to use `setState` in a stateful widget even if you're using BLoC.
I, unfortunately, don't use BloC, but if you can manage the errors messages within BLoC, it could be better since you could use only BLoC and you could use a Stateless widget instead, which will be rebuild less frequently than a stateful one.

In my opinion, there is no major harm using setState and BLoC in the same widget.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a recommended practice to use setState inside a BlocListener (if possible) as BlocListener itself was made to control state (it improves the readability and consistency of the UI). Instead, try to use BlocBuilder on the parts where the rebuild is required. This might limit you from achieving what you want in terms of UI but it can also optimize your app if done correctly. For instance by using BlocBuilder only on widgets where the UI update is required (targeting specific widgets)

```
BlocBuilder<Bloc, BlocState>(
builder:(context, state){
  bool isLoading = state is LoadingBloc;
  return ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: ()=>BlocProvider.of<Bloc>(context).add(BlocEvent),
     style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(size: Size.fromRadius(20),),
     child: isLoading?CircularProgressIndicator():Text('Load data'),
    );
}
```

This is a simple scenario of using BlocBuilder for showing simple loading user feedback. However, this implementation can limit you from achieving complex UI requiring a global state flag and it is in such cases that I rarely myself use setState in the BlocListener.
NB - you can implement your textfield in the same manner as the above example